# Regular Expression for alphabets,numbers,spaces and underscores

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex expression that will match only letters and numbers, one space between each word and underscores?

**Good Examples:**

```
Vamshi1

vamshi_pendota

vamshi pendota
```

**Bad Examples:**

```
vam    shi1

vam_shi      pendota
```

Comment: Why is `vamshi pendota` correct and `vam shi` incorrect?

Comment: updated the question pls check now

Comment: FYI added new [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lT1lC0) that allows numbers to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you provide any further information, I suspect that what you are after cannot be achieved through a regular expression.

Regular expressions are used to match patterns of strings. In your case, the Good and Bad cases you want to match look the same from a pattern perspective.

Assuming that `Vamshi` is a valid name but `Vam shi` is not (despite both having alpha numeric characters and one white space) in your language, I suspect you need to look at a dictionary implementation and not simply a regular expression one.

EDIT: After seeing your change, something like so should work for you: `^[a-z0-9_]+(\s[a-z0-9_]+)*$`. The regular expression should expect the string to start with one or more lower case letters and/or underscores optionally followed by a white space and more text.

Comment: Thanks, how can I change it to allow numbers also?

Comment: To me, `^[a-z_]+` doesn't seem correct because it will allow `_v_a_m_s_h_i_`

Comment: @vamsi: I have amended it to include numbers as well.

Comment: @zx81: I see what you mean. That being said, the OP did not specify, so I provided the *simplest* answer which fitted the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regex tester site like http://regex101.com/

You can enter in your examples, and use the quick reference to help you construct the correct regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

With this simple regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ _][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lT1lC0)

**Option 2 for capitalization**

If only the first letter of each word can be a capital letter, use

```
^[A-Z]?[a-z0-9]+(?:[ _][A-Z]?[a-z0-9]+)?$
```

**What it means**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ _][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

- Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a single character present in the list below `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
  - A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case sensitive) `a-z`
  - A character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case sensitive) `A-Z`
  - A character in the range between “0” and “9” `0-9`
- Match the regular expression below `(?:[ _][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?`

  - Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `?`
  - Match a single character from the list “ _” `[ _]`
  - Match a single character present in the list below `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
    - A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case sensitive) `a-z`
    - A character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case sensitive) `A-Z`
    - A character in the range between “0” and “9” `0-9`
- Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) `$`